# Computer power supply outputs 5.20 volts at 3.3 volts rail

Tags: power-supply, atx

I got an old 420 watt Tagan power supply. It seems pretty good quality. I wanted to convert it into a bench power supply. It worked fine until I THINK I messed things up. I’m not sure if i actually damaged it or it was just too old and broke down. All I did was desolder a bunch of useless wires from the 3.3, 5, 12 volts and ground rails. After I connected it to a power source and measured the voltage at each rail, I found out that the 3.3 rails output was 5.20 volts!!! Why? Is there any way to fix it? Like replace any broken component. Also I did a continuity check between the 5 and 3.3 volt rail. There wasn't any short circuit.

Comment: Some old PSUs have cross regulation with combined feedback. You may have cut at least one of the feedback paths (e.g. damaging the tracks) while removing wires.

Comment: @RohatKılıç all the "useless" wires which i removed were connected to a single point for each kind of voltage. (3,3,5 12 Volts and ground)

Comment: Is the 3.3V rail unloaded? If yes, can you try loading it?

Comment: @winny i put a load on the 3.3 rail. The voltage just dropped to 5.10 volts :(

Comment: How much load did you use?

Comment: @winny i put a 775 motor

Comment: Some PSUs need a minimum load in order to stabilize, so it might not be a good idea for a bench supply

Comment: @DirkBruere i put some load on the power supply but still the voltage was 5.20. Before i desoldered those wires it worked fine

Comment: What's a 775 motor? What’s its current consumption in mA? Anyway, best guess is the one of the wires were a sense wire.

Comment: @winny its a very powerful electric motor

Comment: @SmokingDieselGR The practise of [Muntzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muntzing) requires you to be able to undo the last change before the device stopped working. Can you re-solder the wires to find out which one is *not* useless?

Comment: Sorry, powerful is not an EE term. But listen to Andrew! I bet there is a sense wire!